# Add a legend for ggplot_map

Tags: r, dictionary, legend

I am trying to plot specific colors for specific countries using R maps library and add a legend of the colors with `scale_fill_manual()`

My data frame is «data» and has 3 columns: the first is the countries names, the second is just some numeric data, and the 3rd is the color:

```
              countries toplot     color
1             Argentina     -1       red
2               Armenia     -1       red
3             Australia     -1       red
4               Bahrain     -1       red
5              Botswana     -1       red
6               Belgium     -1       red
7              Bulgaria     -1       red
8                Canada     -1       red
9                 Chile     -1       red
10               Taiwan     -1       red
11              Croatia     -1       red
12       Czech Republic     -1       red
13     UK:Great Britain     -1       red
14                Egypt     -1       red
15              Denmark     -1       red
16              Finland      0    yellow
17               France      0    yellow
18              Georgia      0    yellow
19              Germany      0    yellow
20      China:Hong Kong      0    yellow
21              Hungary      0    yellow
22            Indonesia      0    yellow
23                 Iran      0    yellow
24              Ireland      0    yellow
25               Israel      0    yellow
26                Italy      0    yellow
27                Japan      0    yellow
28               Jordan      0    yellow
29           Kazakhstan      1 darkgreen
30                Korea      1 darkgreen
31               Kuwait      1 darkgreen
32              Lebanon      1 darkgreen
33            Lithuania      1 darkgreen
34             Malaysia      1 darkgreen
35                Malta      1 darkgreen
36              Morocco      1 darkgreen
37          Netherlands      1 darkgreen
38          New Zealand      1 darkgreen
39  UK:Northern Ireland      1 darkgreen
40               Norway      1 darkgreen
41                 Oman      1 darkgreen
42            Palestine      1 darkgreen
43               Poland      1 darkgreen
44             Portugal      1 darkgreen
45                Qatar      1 darkgreen
46               Russia      1 darkgreen
47         Saudi Arabia      0    yellow
48               Serbia      0    yellow
49            Singapore      0    yellow
50      Slovak Republic      0    yellow
51             Slovenia     -1       red
52         South Africa     -1       red
53                Spain     -1       red
54               Sweden     -1       red
55             Thailand      1 darkgreen
56               Turkey      1 darkgreen
57 United Arab Emirates      0    yellow
58                  USA      1 darkgreen
```

This is the code I am using:

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2) 

map = map_data("world")
map = subset(map, region!="Antarctica")

Countries = ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = map, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "gray97", colour="darkgray", size=0.5)+
  geom_map(data=data,map=map,aes(map_id=country, x=lon, y=lat), fill = "cornflowerblue", colour = "gray") +
  coord_equal()
CountriesDif<-Countries +
  geom_map(data = data, map = map, aes(map_id = country), fill = data$color, colour="darkgray") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + # omit plot title saying 'color'
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('darkgreen', 'yellow', 'red'),
                    labels = c('Above Mean', 'At Mean', 'Below Mean'))
CountriesDif + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: MapCountries]
I can get the map with correct colors, but no "Legend" :-(... and I can't figure out why? What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: For `geom_map()`, you have `fill = data$color`. I wonder if this is causing the issue. I think you meant `fill = color` and put that in `aes()`?

Comment: Yes and move inside the `aes`.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry guys, I was using the wrong function. Adding  `scale_fill_identity("Title legend", labels = c("Below mean", "At mean", "Above mean"), breaks = plotclr, guide = "legend")`
does solve my question. I guess that to keep the correct order of colors one needs to use `scale_fill_identity`rather than `scale_fill_manual`.

This is the complete code (for reference to someone else running in the same problem):

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2) 

map = map_data("world")
map = subset(map, region!="Antarctica")

Countries = ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = map, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "gray97", colour="darkgray", size=0.5)+
  coord_equal()

plotclr <- c("red","yellow", "darkgreen")  #Choose the collors you want to plot

CountriesDif<-Countries +
  geom_map(data = data, map = map, aes(map_id = country, fill = color), colour="darkgray") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + # omit plot title saying 'color'
  scale_fill_identity("Title legend", labels = c("Below mean", "At mean", "Above mean"), breaks = plotclr, guide = "legend")

TimssDif + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

And this is the map:
[image]

Thanks for your time.